# Html PHP Comment Box With TXT File

Tags: php, html, linux, apache2, comments

I'd like to create a comment box only using php. Actually I don't know how to use MySQL and honestly i don't even want to for a while. So my problem is that, when I click the submit button while the textarea is empty it's still submit it and it's generate an empty text with a < hr > tag. How can I solve it? I'll be very glad if someone can show me how to do when the textarea is empty when I submit it and an error message is appear.
Here is the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
hr {
        width: 360px;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
  <textarea name="txt" cols="25" rows="5" placeholder="Add your comment here"></textarea>
  <br><br> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
  
  <?php
  if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {
    $com  = $_POST[ "txt" ];
    $file = fopen( "inrg.txt", "a" );
    fwrite( $file, "<br>" );
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= strlen( $com ) - 1; $i++ ) {
      fwrite( $file, $com[ $i ] );
      if ( $i % 37 == 0 && $i != 0 ) fwrite( $file, "<br/>" );
    }
    fwrite( $file, "<br><hr>" );
    fclose( $file );
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location ="/index.php";</script>';
  }
  ?>

  <br>
</form>
<font face="Times New Roman"><b><p>Textul introdus este: </p></b></font>
<font face="Comic Sans MS" color="red" size="2">
  <?php
  if (file_exists("inrg.txt")) {
  $file = fopen( "inrg.txt", "r" );
  echo fread( $file, filesize( "inrg.txt" ) );
  fclose( $file );
  }
  ?>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make the textarea `required`. Or check that `$_POST[ "txt" ]` is actually not empty

Comment: OMG. I feel so stupid. You're right. I could have use the required tag

Comment: You have also other options depending on what you want to do, for example a `onsubmit` function on the form in Javascript, or checking the content of `$_POST[ "txt" ]` in PHP

Comment: Thank you guys! <textarea name="txt" cols="25" rows="5" placeholder="Add your comment here" required="required"></textarea> It's solved my problem. Thank you the fast answers.